# Xamarin Forms Teechart - Draw Image

Tags: xamarin.forms, teechart

Is there a working example for drawing an image inside a steema teechart in xamarin forms? I am really struggling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work either assigning an image to the back wall or panel:

```
  var backImage = new Image();
  backImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://www.steema.com/uploads/news/xamarinforms_280x210.png"));

  tChart1.Walls.Back.Gradient.Visible = false;
  tChart1.Walls.Back.Image = backImage;

  tChart1.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
  tChart1.Panel.Image = backImage;
```

nor drawing it directly on the canvas:

```
void tChart1_BeforeDrawSeries(object sender, Graphics3D g)
{
  Rectangle chartRect = tChart1.Chart.ChartRect;
  var backImage = new Image();
  backImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://www.steema.com/uploads/news/xamarinforms_280x210.png"));

  g.Draw(chartRect, chartRect, backImage, false);
}
```

So I have added this to the bug list ([bug 1299](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1299)). Happens both in iOS and Android.

Comment: Any idea when will this get fixed? :)

Comment: @IliaStoilov I'm working on it, I'll keep you posted. You may also be interested in signing up at bugzilla and add yourself to the CC list to be notified about status updates.

Comment: @IliaStoilov got this working in Android 4. Looks like there's a problem with Android 5 converting Xamarin.Forms.Image to Android.Graphics.Bitmap to be drawn to the canvas. I'll continue investigating.